# Performance degradation migrating app from Spring to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, yourkit

We have a legacy webapp that we would like to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE. We have run a load test on the legacy webapp and then ran the same load test on the version where we migrated to Spring boot while profiling the app using YourKit. We see saw ~50% slower for response times in the migrated app. It's a REST API webapp. We found that there were 2 areas where we saw slowdowns.

- mysql methods (e.g. com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery() PreparedStatement.java)
- ApplicationFilterChain

The mysql method is shown as a hotspot in the Spring Boot app, but not the legacy one even though we're using the same mysql connector and same DB configurations.

**Things we checked/tried**

- We checked that the dependency trees are identical
- All app configurations are identical
- We are running the tomcat in the legacy app and using embedded tomcat in Spring Boot

**Questions**

- Are there are any areas we should be looking into?
- Are there good resources on the web for identifying and fixing performance issues during Spring Boot migrations?
- What have been your experiences with migrating to Spring Boot?
- How else should we be using YourKit to identify performance issues?

**Dependency Differences**

```
mvn dependency:list
```

[Diff of the two dependency lists from calling mvn dependency:list](https://pastebin.com/mKRDFBZd)

Comment: Are you really sure you are using the exact same JDBC/driver configuration? Same driver version (or newer version) etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and the same drivers show up. I kept the same datasource configuration for the migrated app

Comment: The same as in exactly the same (package, version etc.)? Also is that datasource the one actually being used or is the default configured one used. You don't post code, configuration etc. so basically it is a guessing game.

Comment: I added the matching and differing dependencies to pastebin in the original post. That should give some more context